# Best way to display testimonials on a product page?

Tags: conversion

I was wondering what would be the best way to display a set of testimonials/reviews on a product-page for better conversions?

- Giving a tab with the **reviews** heading
- Displaying directly below the products in a slider type

Or maybe something else.

Would be glad if someone with knowledge can provide input in here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got testimonial somewhere in online (twitter, facebook, linkedIn), you can show like [thegrid.io](http://thegrid.io) did: [image: appriciation of the grid.io]

If you don't have, It'd better to show an image (to increase trust), company like this:
[image]

But I highly don't suggest to show your testimonials in carousels, sliders etc. Also, don't write much, write like a twitter post. Just keep it simple :)

Comment: The one *thegrid.io* is using is quite wonderful since it shows the simplicity. But however, I suppose adding up of an image to that would have been better?

Comment: @aneeshjajodia that would be fantastic. The only little problem i see there is missing of designation and company name.

Comment: now that you have edited the post, this one looks more relevant. How about I link you to my brand website where in I've been planning on adding testimonials/reviews which could increase my conversion rate? [link](http://www.creativecases.in) - Here is my brand website. Go on to any of the products. Though everything hasn't been completed yet.

Comment: "But I highly don't suggest to show your testimonials in carousels, sliders etc. " Why, and what are you basing that opinion on?

Comment: @HashimAziz my assumption is that tetimonials is not that type of content people usually click to see more